# Angularfire: Getting nested data from a $firebaseObject in controller

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Firebase newbie here.

In my controller I have a variable called `currentChallenge` that contains the following $firebaseObject:

```
$$conf: {sync: {…}, ref: X, binding: f, listeners: Array(0)}
$id: "gRH2EWGQB6dbejKYap40Z0ea0nz2"
$priority: null
-Kuy9HAfvVIhPhtQraLy:
  challenge: {...}
  challenger: "gRH2EWGQB6dbejKYap40Z0ea0nz2"
  pending: true
  timestamp: 1506428920780
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

In Firebase it looks like:
[image]

The code from my controller is as follows:

```
Challenge.lastChallenge(uid, challengeUserId).$loaded()
  .then(function (currentChallenge) {
    if (currentChallenge.challenger == uid) {
      // stuff happens
    }
```

This is calling the Challenge service method:

```
lastChallenge: function (uid1, uid2) {
   var path = uid1 < uid2 ? uid1 + '/' + uid2 : uid2 + '/' + uid1;
   return $firebaseObject(userChallengeRef
     .child(path)
     .orderByChild('timestamp')
     .limitToLast(1));
},
```

The data I am trying to access is `challenger`, however I am unsure how to do this as `$value` doesn't seem to work on objects.

I can't put `-Kuy9HAfvVIhPhtQraLy` because this is subject to change depending on which challenge I'm looking at. It is also not always going to be the same value as `$id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing a query against Firebase:

```
userChallengeRef
  .child(path)
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
  .limitToLast(1))
```

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

That means that you'll need to use `$firebaseArray` to get the result(s) and iterate over it/them. When using the regular JavaScript SDK, it'll be something like this:

```
lastChallenge: function (uid1, uid2) {
   var path = uid1 < uid2 ? uid1 + '/' + uid2 : uid2 + '/' + uid1;
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     userChallengeRef
       .child(path)
       .orderByChild('timestamp')
       .limitToLast(1))
       .once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
         snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
           resolve($firebaseObject(child.ref));
         });
       });
}
```

Invoke it as:

```
Challenge.lastChallenge(uid, challengeUserId).then(function(firebaseObject){ 
  firebaseObject.$loaded().then(function (currentChallenge) {
    if (currentChallenge.challenger == uid) {
      // stuff happens
    }
```

Note that I don't think using AngularFire helps you at all here. You should only be using AngularFire services for things that you bind directly to your Angular UI. For all other operations, just use the Firebase JavaScript SDK directly. It keeps your code simpler, and makes it easier to reason about your app's logic vs its UI.

Comment: Ok how do I add this to currentChallenge variable? After adding this I get a promise rather than the challenge data. Thanks and sorry if this question seems dumb.

Comment: Added a sample.